Add info (like occupation) to a family tree in Gramps
In Gramps, when I create a Family Lines Graph, for each person, it shows specific info: name, dates of birth / death, places of birth death.
Can I add other info to this graph? I'd like to add occupation.
I have found a workaround for how to do this manually. Set the output to be a graphviz file, which is a text file. Then go inside the file and add any info you want for any person. Then convert the graphviz file to an image file. This works, but I have to add in the info manually every time I generate a graph.
Can I have Gramps add this info automatically?

Current solution
I have analysed the code found at the FamilyLines.py (now gvfamilylines.py) plugin file. In the write_people() method we can see which data the plugin can use to generate its text:

name (also surname is used for colour)
person_id
birth date
birth place
death date
death place
image
gender (for card shape and colour)

This means that adding person's occupation is not supported out of the box in Family Lines Graph.
Other solutions
Considering other report types
Some other report types have occupations in them out of the box, like for example the Relationship Graph. Of course, other reports are not the Family Lines report, so that's a subpar solution.
Making your own
If you know GRAMPS plugin/addon creation and some Python, adding occupation to the method should be pretty trivial. Occupation is outputted for example in VCard, which can function as a template.

Thank you for going into so much depth with the answer.
